# How to make run-nifi.bat working for windows

Tags: database, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-nifi

I had downloaded nifi and tried to install but run-nifi.bat not working. On the cmd, when I execute run-nifi the results is weird and not able to open localhost:8080/nifi on my server. Please advice me. The output of the run-nifi on cmd is as belows.

D:\nifi-1.6.0\bin>run-nifi
Failed to determine if Process 4520 is running; assuming that it is not
2023-02-08 11:43:58,367 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2023-02-08 11:43:58,367 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: D:\nifi-1.6.0
2023-02-08 11:43:58,367 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe -classpath D:\nifi-1.6.0.\conf;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\nifi-api-1.6.0.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.6.0.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.6.0.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\nifi-properties-1.6.0.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.6.0.jar;D:\nifi-1.6.0.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=D:\nifi-1.6.0.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=53098 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=D:\nifi-1.6.0\bin..\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi

2023-02-08 11:43:58,844 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file D:\nifi-1.6.0\bin..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2023-02-08 11:43:58,860 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file D:\nifi-1.6.0\bin..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2023-02-08 11:43:58,860 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 5776

Comment: Try running bat file as admin, right click on it and you will see run as admin option.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde, I tried that one too. But still same issues. The cmd console disappear after 3 seconds and localhost for nifi not responding.

Comment: Could you check and send nifi-app.log? It may has an error.